# SQL Structure for JPA- Rows or columns?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm writing a small quiz application and trying to structure the database. 
The basic idea is to have a user answer rate a fixed amount of questions (1-10 answer), and to generate a result based on these answers.

I am having some trouble with the implementation of the database structure - I am not sure wether to have all the answers in one row but different columns, or to have one row for each answers (which results in many rows with only three or four columns)

The database diagram I was thinking is something like below:

*One user can only have one result, and one result belongs to one user*

*One user can answer many questions, one answer belongs to one user*

*Each answer belongs to only one question, but one question can have multiple answers (many users answering)*

[image]

These are my database tables with this implementation:

#### Result Table

```
| ResultID (PK) | UserID (FK)  | TotalScore | ResultText|
```

#### User Table

```
| UserID (PK)  | Name | Email  | Name |
```

#### Answer Table

```
| AnswerID (PK) | QuestionID (FK)  | UserID (FK) | Answer |
```

#### Question Table

```
| QuestionID (PK) | Question |
```

This structure creates nine new rows for a finished quiz, which seems like a lot of unneccessary "space" in the database if these could be fit into a single row using columns for each question (question 1 - question 9).

However, this gave me some issues with JPA & Hibernate, since I had to create variables for each question (leading to tons of redundancy-ish). This approach should at least let me have just one List array to keep all nine questions in.

**The thing I am worried about is the amount of rows that will occupy the database. There will be roughly 10 000-15 000 people answering this quiz, so will over 90 000 rows for just this simple implementation be too much to impact the speed of the DB queries or is it fine to keep it like above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here, is that you don't need an answer table. Since the data inside it will never be updated. So you could use only one column to represent all answers of an user, like a `JSON` column.

With `postgresql` you can do it by adding a JSON column, but if you're using NoSQL you can do it better. I don't see the necessity for one row answer since you have users's result separated. It's an unmodifiable value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are completely right. It felt really unnecessary since these results will be static like you say (i.e. never changing). I am indeed using postgresql but I had no idea about a JSON column, thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: :) I'm here to help. Please accept answer I need points hahaha